Why am I getting error when uploading image using cloud functions?
This is my error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'originalname')

at undefined. ( /workspace/src/routes/upload.js:13 )
at .Layer.handle ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95 )
at .next ( /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:149 )
at .Immediate._onImmediate ( /workspace/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53 )
at process.processImmediate ( node:internal/timers:478 )
at process.topLevelDomainCallback ( node:domain:161 )
at process.callbackTrampoline ( node:internal/async_hooks:126 )

When I upload file locally using node and multer file is uploading, but when i deploy function and try to use it i got an error.
That is an api post:
router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.file;
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    const blob = bucket.file("car_images/" + file.originalname);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();

    blobStream.on("error", (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

    blobStream.on("finish", () => {
      // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
      const publicUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${
        bucket.name
      }/o/${encodeURI(blob.name)}?alt=media`;

      res.status(200).send(publicUrl);
    });

    blobStream.end(file.buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

And that's a frontend function that sends file to backend:
async onUpload() {
      if (!this.image) {
        alert("Please select an image to upload.");
        return;
      }

      const image = new FormData();
      image.append("image", this.image);

      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "https://us-central1-car-hub-130b6.cloudfunctions.net/api/upload",
          // "http://localhost:8000/upload",
          image,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );
        alert("Image uploaded successfully");
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Upload Error:", error);
        alert("Error uploading image");
      }
    },

Also my storage rulse looks like this:
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

I already tried to use Uint8Array(), but that didn't help me, any suggestions?

Maybe there is an issue on front when I upload the file? Because after adding this line:
if (!req.file) {       return res.status(400).send("No file uploaded.");     }
It return me 400 error. Which dependencies should I use to upload file correctly using google-cloud-functions?

Everything seems fine, you have been using the correct dependencies for upload a file. Share the multer (upload) config may be there might an issue

@YuvarajM,
// Configure multer for file upload with memory storage const storage = multer.memoryStorage(); const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

Is it even possible to load a file using google-cloud-functions? Because in logs I've got this: Uploaded file info: undefined . I added this line for logging: if (!file) {     return res.status(400).send("No file uploaded.");   }
